# How do I map a List to a SelectList in ASP.NET MVC using AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have a List of data that I want to bind to a SelectList in my ViewModel.

How do I do this using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If we suppose that you have a model:

```
public class FooModel
{
    public int ModelId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

you could then have a mapping between `FooModel` and `SelectListItem`:

```
Mapper
    .CreateMap<FooModel, SelectListItem>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ModelId.ToString())
    )
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Text, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Description)
    );
```

and then when you've got your `IEnumerable<FooModel>` you would simply convert it to an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`:

```
IEnumerable<FooModel> models = ...
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> viewModels = Mapper
    .Map<IEnumerable<FooModel>, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>(models);
```

A more realistic example would be to have the following view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedItemId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

So now your controller action could look like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<FooModel> items = ...
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel
    {
        Items = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<FooModel>, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>(items)
    };
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

and inside your strongly typed view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedItemId, 
    new SelectList(Model.Items, "Value", "Text")
)
```

Comment: so you have to use select list items? Could you some how have SelectList in the view model instead of having to make it in the view? The way you have it is fine just curious if you can do that as I always had select List in my view model.

Comment: Also the "Value" and "Text" are always null. I am not sure why. In my code I am binding not to a List of Models but to a list of my domain objects. So maybe it can't match up these names(as I don't have anything called "Value" or "Text") is there a way I can tell it what to use?

Comment: I guess have to use your create map. I thought it was only for option way number 1 and I am using option number 2. Also what does "opt" stand for? Option?

Comment: Answer is not full. How would u map SelectListGroup target property?